# How to convert a float64 variable into a string?

Tags: string, type-conversion

I try to convert my float64 variable into str with :
`data['Abo_str'] = data['Abo'].isnull().astype(str)`
But the result is False.
How can I do it ?
Thx

Comment: In what language?

Answer (score 0):

In which language you are implementing If you are implementing in Python. The below code can be useful for you.

```
float_value = 1.99
string_value = str(float_value)
print(string_value)
```

Comment: I'm using Python on Spyder.
But I tried this code but the result is "False".
I have my "Abo" variable in my "data" dataframe, and I want to create or convert the "Abo" variable which is a float64 into a string.